# Why cant I change the SelectedIndex of a combobox from the perspective of another form?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I'm pretty new to C# programming so please forgive my probably super bad mistakes. I have a combobox in SuperAdventure.cs (cboWeapons) and I cant seem to change it from the level of the second form (InventoryScreen.cs) via the following button:

```
private void btnEquipWeapon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SuperAdventure weapon = new SuperAdventure();
    String CurrentWeapon = this.cboCurrentWeapon.GetItemText(this.cboCurrentWeapon.SelectedItem);
    weapon.cboWeapons_SelectedItemChange(CurrentWeapon);
}
```

And here is the cboWeapons_SelectedItemChange method from SuperAdventure.cs:

```
public void cboWeapons_SelectedItemChange(string weapon)
{
    cboWeapons.SelectedIndex = cboWeapons.FindString(weapon);
}
```

The cboWeapons combobox is data bound but I believe that would not make too much of a difference in this case? Also, I was able to change it using a test button I made in SuperAdventure form by just:

```
private void btnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cboWeapons.SelectedIndex = cboWeapons.FindString("Sword");
}
```

And yes, I am making a silly RPG based on Scott Lilly's tutorial in C# with mostly my own forms classes etc... Hope someone will be able to help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SuperAdventure weapon = new SuperAdventure();` creates a new form and does not interact with an existing form. That said, if you use `weapon.Show()` you will have your new form shown, any other existing forms will not be affected. Moreover, on form initialization nothing is selected from the combobox so even the new form will not have any changes unless you specify the selected index in the constructor

Comment: If you add the `weapon.Show();` line @AmmarSalman referred to, immediately following the `SuperAdventure weapon= new SuperAdventure();` line, I believe you will experience a revelation.  It will likely lead to more questions.  I encourage you to keep at it.

Comment: Holy mother of objective programming.. You gentlemen made me realise how stupid I am.. So how would I create a method that could essentially make a combobox change the selecteditem in a combobox from a different class/form? Do I not need to instantiate the class in this btnEquipWeapon_Click ?

Comment: @hawkeyegold the way it is can never work. He's just creating a new form and it is unrelated to the existing form (if any). He cannot change value from other form unless they are related (one creates the other, or both created by another form). `SuperAdventure weapon = new SuperAdventure();` does NOTHING to the already running SuperAdventure form. Besides, what solution would you suggest?

Comment: @AmmarSalman you are absolutely right, would you have any advice how can I actually make it so that I can do something to the running SuperAdventure form in the other form please?

Comment: @AmmarSalman I agree.  I just believe if he shows it, and sees it, he'll better understand why it isn't doing what he is expecting.  But I've been wrong before :)

Comment: @M.Osuch First we need to understand how are you calling each form and where to understand the relation between the two forms.

Comment: @hawkeyegold Ohh I can see now. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Both forms have the comboboxes filled out by databinding like so: cboCurrentWeapon.DataSource = _currentPlayer.Weapons;

Comment: Yup, I can see that, but how are you creating each of the two forms?

Comment: The InventoryScreen form I am creating in the SuperAdventure form by a button and I create it as an object like so InventoryScreen inventoryScreen = new InventoryScreen(_player); //_player is the player object I create from a different class at the beginning of the SuperAdventure form. The constructor from the InventoryScreen is as following:            public InventoryScreen(Player player)
        {
            _currentPlayer = player;
            InitializeComponent();
            cboCurrentWeapon.DataSource = _currentPlayer.Weapons;
            cboCurrentWeapon.DisplayMember = "Name";

Comment: You might take a look at MusiGenesis answer from this question.  It might get you going in the right direction.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443932/accessing-main-form-from-child-form

Comment: I made an answer, it should work for you. Comment there and tell me what happens with you @M.Osuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution (I would not really recommend for big projects) would be like this: First, add a private field in `InventoryScreen` of the `SuperAdventure` form type. Then add `SuperAdventure` type to your constructor of `InventoryScreen`. This way when you call `InventoryScreen` you will pass your `SuperAdventure` handler to the new `InventoryScreen` and from that handle you can make changes to the original existing `SuperAdventure` form.

```
SuperAdventure callingForm;

InventoryScreen(Player player, SuperAdventure callingForm) {    
    InitializeComponent(); 
    _currentPlayer = player;
    this.callingForm = callingForm;
    cboCurrentWeapon.DataSource = _currentPlayer.Weapons; 
    cboCurrentWeapon.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

When you call InventoryScreen just pass `this` as another parameter like:

```
InventoryScreen iv = new InventoryScreen(player, this);
```

Finally, the button in InventoryScreen would change to:

```
private void btnEquipWeapon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String CurrentWeapon = this.cboCurrentWeapon.GetItemText(this.cboCurrentWeapon.SelectedItem);
        callingForm.cboWeapons_SelectedItemChange(CurrentWeapon);
    }
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS !! Thank you very much my friend you made my day.

Comment: It worked exactly as I wanted it to work Ammar. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = me.ComboBox2.SelectedIndex
```

Thats in vb.net but you can translate and try i think

Comment: How is this related?