# How to control parent form from modally called child form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to control the parent form from a modal child form?

My only idea is to close the parent form and show child form via `ChildForm.Show()` and not `ChildForm.ShowDialog(parentform)`, can I control parent form from modally displayed child form?

How to refresh a parent form automatically upon saving the update on the child form?

Comment: You may searching for the [MdiParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent?view=netframework-4.7.2) property

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443932/accessing-main-form-from-child-form

You are a new contributor, please try to search for your problem first before posting the question, this saves you time :-)

Comment: See my two form project.  You need to use instance of the parent that is passed to child : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: yeah, im trying to learn coding on my own, sorry im not really good at it yet but all your comments helped me. thnk you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent (Owner) form by using `Owner` property. If you show the dialog using:

```
childForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

(***this*** will be the form from where you are showing the dialog)

then in the dialog:

```
this.Owner.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Coral;
```

This will change the background colour of the parent form immediately.

`ParentForm` is available in the context of `MDIForm` context.

Comment: Accept it as an answer that helps other people find the solution easily.